# 'npm ERR! missing script: ngcc' error con NPM

Tags: angular, npm

De un día para el otro mi proyecto en visual studio code comenzó a mostrar estos dos errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Casi todos los tags de Angular Material me los marcá como si no fueran etiquetas reconocidas. Pero si cambio de archivo en el navegador de VS las lineas donde figuraba el error se replica en un .ts por ejemplo (como si estuviera buggeado).
Traté con npm run ngcc pero este error aparece:
npm ERR! missing script: ngcc

También traté borrando la carpeta de node modules y package-lock y reinstalar npm pero sigue con lo mismo.

Mi package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-io-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Example project from an angular.io guide.",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "test": "karma start karma.webpack.conf.js",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --bail",
    "dev": "rimraf build && webpack -w --config config/webpack.dev.js",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.5",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.5",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "4.4.5",
    "@angular/upgrade": "4.4.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "@ngui/auto-complete": "0.13.8",
    "@ngui/map": "0.18.4",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.30.0",
    "@types/underscore": "1.8.5",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.3.1",
    "angular-router-loader": "0.6.0",
    "angular2-moment": "1.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "2.7.1",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.6.1",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "latest-version": "^5.1.0",
    "moment": "2.19.2",
    "ng-block-ui": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "ng-click-outside": "2.4.1",
    "ng-fullcalendar": "^1.7.1",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "4.2.0",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.7",
    "ng2-datetime": "1.4.0",
    "ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker": "0.0.5",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.2.1",
    "ng2-simple-global": "1.2.4",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "4.0.0",
    "ng2-table": "1.3.2",
    "ng4-charts": "1.0.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "1.7.1",
    "ngx-chips": "1.5.9",
    "ngx-embed-video": "^0.3.0",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "1.1.0",
    "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
    "ngx-toastr": "5.2.5",
    "primeng": "5.0.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.112",
    "@types/node": "6.0.92",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.3.0",
    "css-loader": "0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-beta.5",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.16.1",
    "jasmine": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "karma": "1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.6",
    "lodash": "4.16.2",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.16",
    "protractor": "4.0.14",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "tslint": "3.15.1",
    "typescript": "2.2.0",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.1",
    "webpack-merge": "3.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi versión de angular cli:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes compartir tu package.json?

Comment: Ahí edite el post!

Comment: Puedes abrir el apartado `Settings` de VS y en la barra de búsqueda poner `@ext:angular.ng-template` y actualizar tu pregunta con eso, además de compartir tu versión de angular-cl? Gracias.

Comment: Dale, ya subí las imagenes

Comment: Intenta agregar a tus scripts `"postinstall": "ngcc"`. Despues haces un `npm install`. La verdad tambien soy algo nuevo en angular y me surge la duda, por que levantas con `"start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080"` y no con `ng serve -o`?

Comment: Es un proyecto del trabajo, lo corremos por otro lado.

Comment: @CamilaMargni que información te muestra al darle clic al botón "Show Ouput"? De casualidad ejecutaste algo como `npm audit --fix`?